# toString() method that returns a string representation of a maze

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a toString() method that turns a 2d Char array that represents a maze into a string representation.

```
public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < map.length;i++){
        s += Arrays.toString(map[i]);
    }
    return s;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Maze maze = new Maze();
    String filename = args[0];
    maze.initializeFromFile(filename);
    String path = maze.findPath();
    map[startRow][startCol] = 'S';
    System.out.println(map.toString());
    System.out.println(path);
}
```

But this gives me output like this. I read here that this is pointer address or something to do with memory location, but i don't know what to do with this. i can get the output i want when i just use a simple loop in my Main to print each row, but whenever i try to use this method i always get this sort of output.

```
[[C@5c647e05
```

This is the maze i was given from a text file.

```
10 10
##########
#        #
#   ###  #
#   #  G #
#   #    #
#        #
#        #
#  #######
#   S    #
##########
```

This is how i initialize my char Array

```
public class Maze {

public static char[][] map;
public static int startRow;
public static int startCol;
public static int mapHeight;
public static int mapWidth;

public void initializeFromFile(String filename){
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        mapHeight = scanner.nextInt();
        mapWidth = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        map = new char[mapHeight][mapWidth];
        for(int i = 0; i < map.length;i++){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            map[i] = line.toCharArray();
            for(int j = 0; j < map[i].length;j++){
                if(map[i][j] == 'S'){
                    startRow = i;
                    startCol = j;
                }
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually `toString` method is suppose to return simplified one-line String including information about object which can be easily included in log file. If your method need to generate multi-line response then maybe create separate method like `void printMaze()` instead of `toString()`. Also you shouldn't close your resources inside `try` block since if something bad will happen before that line you will never call `close()` method. Move it to `finally` block, or better start using try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you print a java array using toString it just prints the id of the array. If you use `Arrays.toString(map)` that will do more like what you want.

It sounds like in this case you will actually need `Arrays.deepToString(map)` since you have nested arrays.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[])

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.deepToString(2dArray)`, but the print out will be a one liner output.

If you want the print out to be 2D looking (table form), you may consider overriding the toString method of your Maze class (Since you can't override your 2D array - map).

```
class Maze(){
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int x=0; x<map.length; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<map[0].length; y++)
                sb.append(map[x][y]);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

***To print out the map:***

Instead of `System.out.println(map.toString());`, just print the `maze` which is backed by a `map`.

```
System.out.println(maze);
```

Comment: **Remarks:** If I were you, I will implement the printing of the map in a self-defined method like `print()` or `printMap()` instead of doing it in the `toString()`.